# Exit Private Mode to Log In Please open a regular browsing window to log in. You can also continue as a guest to chat with this business

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, microsoft-edge, facebook-chatbot

Why it is not possible to open in some computer browser - chrome and Microsoft edge to chat with facebook chat plugin on website. When clicking on Log into Messenger - got this error.

**"Exit Private Mode to Log In
Please open a regular browsing window to log in. You can also continue as a guest to chat with this business"**

The URL on the new window while give this message is https://www.facebook.com/plugins/chat/incognito_login/.

But it is working on Firefox browser. However for the same website FB chat plugin work on another computer chrome browser, how is it?

What setup is needed in my laptop browser for able to chat in messenger of website of FB plugin from the chrome and edge.

There was not a problem like one year before but I think since nearly one year this error came. I think there is something wrong with facebook chat plugin after they upgraded. I try to contact them but there is no proper support from facebook.

I hope someone will help to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to launch this chat plugin in the `inprivate` mode? If yes, for testing purposes try to use the normal browsing window to see whether it is working with the Edge and Chrome browser. If it works then it can possible that there are some limitations of the Facebook chat plugin and it can't work in `inprivate` mode.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT No, not in private mode. I use normal mode in chrome and edge.  But It is not working on both in private mode and normal mode too.

Comment: It can be possible that there may be some issue with the Facebook chat plugin. I suggest you try to contact the support service for the Facebook chat plugin. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I also think so. But I tried to contact Facebook support but could not able to contact. They don't respond at all.

Comment: hello, this is due to some extension install in computer or browser. Recently I've formatted my laptop for upgrading the ssd. Now when install new chrome, and even on ms edge, it is working. But I don't know which extension is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to extension installed on browser and computer, but which extension I am not sure. I had extension like grammarly, dictionary, dashlane, radio and more before.

I have formatted my old hdd to upgrade ssd of my laptop. And I installed all new OS, and browser too. And it is working now.